# Alter HTML real-time with input tag

Tags: javascript, input

How can I can I alter (change, add, whatever) HTML/text real-time using the `input` tag? Very similar to the preview interface when asking a question on Stack Overflow minus the code encoding. It just has to be simple.

For example,

```
<input type="text" name="whatever" />
<div id="example"></div>
```

Whatever text is entered in the above `input` tag is added to `#example` in real-time.
Something involving `innerHTML` and JavaScript perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var a = $(this).val();
    $('#example').text(a); 
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5TnGT/

Comment: Glad that I could help @UserIsCorrupt!

Answer (score 2):

There are many other ways to change content than described in the previous answers. Listen for all of them and update realtime. Requires jQuery supporting the newer `.on()` event handling for this example. Can also use `.bind()` or `.live()` with appropriate syntax.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('keyup propertychange input paste', 'input', function() {
        $('#example').text($(this).val());
    }); 
});
```

The second $(document) can be made more specific depending on the markup of the rest of your page.

See also: [http://jsfiddle.net/DccuN/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/DccuN/)

Comment: This just got an upvote so I figured I'd come back along and clarify. Don't use .live() unless you have no other option due to a jQuery version that only has .live. Use .on or .delegate when available. Also, I'd previously referenced .html() which would allow arbitrary Javascript to be injected into the page. Granted, anyone can do that with a console anyway, but I wanted to change it to .text() to eliminate the  possibility that I was promoting a page vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

Yes javascript will do this. Have a look at [on key up](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp). Then either innerHTML as you say or jQuery makes things a bit easier with [.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or .html or .text

(Damn too slow)

Answer (score 0):

Plain JavaScript solution (you won't need any sophisticated lib if you don't get too fancy elsewhere):

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="document.getElementById('example').innerHTML=this.value;" name="whatever" />
<div id="example"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the keyup event. Then set the div contents to that of the input.

http://jsfiddle.net/wYqgc/

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
var div = document.getElementById('example');
input.onkeyup = function() {
    div.innerHTML = this.value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this:

```
input.onkeyup = function () {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/P4jS9/